# How to subset a data frame in R based on pattern matches from a list?

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I am trying to subset a data frame in R to contain rows with patterns matched from a list of desired pattern matches. Conceptually, my data frame looks like this:

```
>data1
a           b
train       2.00
racecar     5.00
motorcycle  3.00
streetcar   1.50
bicycle     1.00
truck       2.50
plane       6.00
```

I would like to subset the data frame to include those rows containing the patterns from a list, for example:

```
list <- c("car", "cycle")
```

I would like to get a subset of the data frame like this:

```
>data2
a          b
racecar    5.00
motorcycle 3.00
streetcar  1.50
bicycle    1.00
```

My actual data frame and list are much longer.

I tried

```
data2<-data[data1$a %like% list, ]
```

but this just returns the match to the first pattern in the list and "Warning: argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

```
>data2
a         b
racecar   5.00
streetcar 1.50
```

I then tried to make a loop to work through the patterns in the list iteratively, but I couldn't get it to work:

```
df <- data.frame()

 for (i in 1:length(list)) { output<-data1[data1$a %like% i, ]
     df = rbind(df,output)}
```

The code runs, but returns an empty data table. I wonder if anyone knows how to make this work, or if another solution is possible.

Comment: You don't need a loop, just `unlist` your `list` and apply the solution from the above link. i.e. `subset(data1, grepl(paste0(unlist(list), collapse = "|"), a))` or `data1[grepl(paste0(unlist(list), collapse = "|"), data1$a),]`

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work on my larger dataset!